# Showing different fonts to user

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using Extjs 4.1.0 and I want to show user different fonts may be in the form of combobox/option like what we get to see in editors like **Wordpad** or **MS Word**.

Is there is some way to achieve it. I don't want to go for 'HTML editor' as I won't be providing Editor but just will be displaying a setting page to show all options like - Font, Font Size, Font Color.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide custom template for combo. For example:

```
var combo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    store: store,
    renderTo: 'combo',
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="x-boundlist-item" style="font-family: \'{name}\'">{name}</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    )
});
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/k2JbL/5/

Comment: Extending your example, this shows how to apply the font-family, size, and color to another element:  http://jsfiddle.net/k2JbL/47/

Answer (score 0):

You can embed html tags for the field labels

fieldLabel:combo box name